# Copy half an Array into a new one

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

I am trying to copy half an Array with an loop into an other Array.
so i want half the array for A1 and the other half for A0. its for a recursively Algorithm.
problem is, the copy does not work
it looks like this right now:

```
    A1 = new int[A.length / 2];
    A0 = new int[A.length - A1.length];

    for (int i = 0; i <= A.length / 2; i++) {
    A1 [i] = A [i];
    }
```

Comment: Btw, `Arrays.copyOfRange` might be easier.

Comment: Once you have the A1 array allocated, use its length to copy (And don't use <= since arrays are zero based).   And you never copy anything to A0.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` as Andy Turner suggested, this is pretty painless:

```
        int[] a = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
        
        int[] a1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length / 2);
        int[] a0 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, a.length / 2, a.length);
        
        System.out.println("a1: " + Arrays.toString(a1));
        System.out.println("a0: " + Arrays.toString(a0));
```

Output:

> ```
> a1: [2, 3]
> a0: [5, 7, 11]
> ```

### What went wrong in your code?

WJS gave us the clue: By using `<=` in the condition `i <= A.length / 2` you are trying to copy into a non-existing element of `A1`. This gives you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. When `A1` has length `A.length / 2`, then its elements are indexed 0, 1, … up to `A.length / 2 - 1` inclusive. There is no element `A.length / 2`, yet your loop will run one final time with `i` set to this value.

### Documentation link

[`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] A0 = new int[A.length / 2];
    int[] A1 = new int[A.length - A0.length];

    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (i < A.length / 2)
            A0[i] = A[i];
        else {
            A1[j++] = A[i];
        }
    }
```

**or even simpler**

```
int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] A0 = new int[A.length / 2];
    int[] A1 = new int[A.length - A0.length];

    System.arraycopy(A,0,A0,0,A.length/2);
    System.arraycopy(A,A.length/2,A1,0,A1.length);
```

arraycopy(Object source, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)

source − This is the source array.

srcPos − This is the starting position in the source array.

dest − This is the destination array.

destPos − This is the starting position in the destination data.

length − This is the number of array elements to be copied.

Comment: Don't use an if inside a loop like that. Use two loops.

Comment: Tell me the reason please.

Comment: it's just unnecessary. You're checking the value of i, then checking the value of i. Doing two checks is unnecessary, because the condition is always false once it becomes false. If you structure it as two loops, you only need to check i once per iteration